# Image corrupting PDF file when generated on server; does not happen when generated by client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, jspdf

I am using [JSPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf) to generate PDF files on the client side of an application for all browsers beyond IE 8 to be off-line compatible.  Since JSPDF does nto work with IE8 (IE8 limits the size of an HTTP GET), the solution has been to do a post to an API action that will save the file on the server and return a link to the client that it is hosted at (IE8 support does NOT need to be offline capable).

I am posting the raw bytes output by JSPDF to the server and it can save the PDF just fine so long as there is no image in the PDF.  When there is an image, the data is corrupted and it causes a memory overflow when trying to open the file.

Why would the image be encrypted incorrectly?  My initial guess was that the raw bytes contained an illegal character, but a quick check of the PDF file source indicates that is probably not the case.

**Controller Action:**

```
public struct PdfBytesContainer
{
     public byte[] RawPdfBytes { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public string Post(PdfBytesContainer container)
{
    var fileName = "test";
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"PathToFile\File.pdf", container.RawPdfBytes);
    return fileName;
}
```

**AJAX POST:**

```
var pdfData = {
    rawPdfBytes: doc.output()//.substring(0, 100)
};
$.ajax({
    url: pdfApiUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: pdfData,
    success: function(response) {
        var url = "/Content/Pdfs/" + response + ".pdf";
            window.open(url,'_blank');
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert("failed " + response);
    }
});
```

Note: I have also tried using a string instead of a byte[] in the PdfBytesContainer struct. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a Blob[1] or an ArrayBuffer[2] rather than raw bytes.

[1] : doc.output("blob");

[2] : doc.output("arraybuffer"); // requires latest jsPDF version

I.e:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("csrf", someToken);
fd.append("blob", doc.output("blob"));
$.ajax({
   url: pdfApiUrl,
   type: "POST",
   data: fd,
   processData: false,
   contentType: "multipart/form-data",
   ...
});
```

Obviously you'll need to adapt the server-side code, too.